# jquery remove/addClass being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to make a *slider* of my own, without templates. But I have ran into an issue *already*.

When I attempt to `removeClass('active')` or attempt to `addClass('active')` after `.children().fadeOut(300)` or `.children().fadeIn(300)` *and possibly even more*, it seems to be ignored.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOfSlides = $('div.slider > div').children().length;
  var i = 0;

  while (i < numOfSlides) {
    $('div.slides div.count').append('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i>');
    i++;
  };
  i = 0;

  $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)')
    .addClass('active')
    .children().fadeIn(300);
  $('div.slides i.fa:nth-child(1)')
    .removeClass("fa-circle-o")
    .addClass("fa-circle");

  window.setInterval(function() {
    $('div.slider div.active')
      .children().fadeOut(300)
      .removeClass('active');    ///<-- the issue
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide cnt-main wrp">
    <div class="cnt-mdl">
      <div class="cnt-inr content">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <p>Aliquam convallis pharetra feugiat. Quisque euismod ipsum arcu, eget lacinia leo faucibus vel. Donec eget augue nec lorem rutrum ultricies sit amet eget orci. Vivamus quis tortor vel erat aliquet elementum sit amet elementum diam. Phasellus gravida
          metus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cnt-inr content">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <p>Aliquam convallis pharetra feugiat. Quisque euismod ipsum arcu, eget lacinia leo faucibus vel. Donec eget augue nec lorem rutrum ultricies sit amet eget orci. Vivamus quis tortor vel erat aliquet elementum sit amet elementum diam. Phasellus gravida
          metus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides cnt-main">
    <div class="cnt-mdl">
      <div class="cnt-inr count">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any reason why it might be ignoring things after running `.children().fadeIn(300)` or `.children().fadeOut(300)` ?

**Edit** I managed to make a work around and it seems to be working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOfSlides = $('div.slider > div').children().length;
  var activeIndex;
  var i = 0;

  while(i <= numOfSlides) {
    $('div.slides div.count').append('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i>');
    i++;
  };
  i = 0;

  $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)')
    .addClass('active')
    .children().fadeIn(300);

  activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;

  $('div.slides i.fa:nth-child(1)')
    .removeClass("fa-circle-o")
    .addClass("fa-circle");

  window.setInterval(function() {
    $('div.slider div.active').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).children().fadeOut(300);
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      if(activeIndex <= numOfSlides) {
        $(this).next('.content').addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.content').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).next('.content').children().fadeIn(300);

        activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;

        $('div.slides i.fa-circle')
          .removeClass('fa-circle')
          .addClass('fa-circle-o');
        $('div.slides i:nth-child(' +activeIndex+ ')')
          .removeClass('fa-circle-o')
          .addClass('fa-circle');
      } else {
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'block');
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').children().fadeIn(300);

        activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;

        $('div.slides i.fa-circle')
          .removeClass('fa-circle')
          .addClass('fa-circle-o');
        $('div.slides i:nth-child(' +activeIndex+ ')')
          .removeClass('fa-circle-o')
          .addClass('fa-circle');
      };
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: use complete callback instead of chaining function call

 https://jsfiddle.net/t7y6h5dy/

Comment: @JonathanAnctil even when using the answer given by @vojtech-b `.removeClass()` still gets ignored

Comment: I think your selector $('div.slider div.active').children() is wrong. What I get is the first section element but there's no active class. The parent element is active instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to remove the class after the fadeOut?
In that case use callback:

```
$('div.slider div.active').children().fadeOut(300, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Even when using this code `.removeClass('active')` still gets ignored for me (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure it out, thanks for the help that you guys offered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOfSlides = $('div.slider > div').children().length;
  var activeIndex;
  var i = 0;

  while(i <= numOfSlides) {
    $('div.slides div.count').append('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i>');
    i++;
  };
  i = 0;

  $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)')
    .addClass('active')
    .children().fadeIn(300);

  activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;

  $('div.slides i.fa:nth-child(1)')
    .removeClass("fa-circle-o")
    .addClass("fa-circle");

  window.setInterval(function() {

    $('div.slider div.active').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).children().fadeOut(300);
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      if(activeIndex <= numOfSlides) {
        $(this).next('.content').addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.content').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).next('.content').children().fadeIn(300);

        activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;
        console.log(activeIndex);

        $('div.slides i.fa-circle')
          .removeClass('fa-circle')
          .addClass('fa-circle-o');
        $('div.slides i:nth-child(' +activeIndex+ ')')
          .removeClass('fa-circle-o')
          .addClass('fa-circle');
      } else {
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'block');
        $('div.slider div.content:nth-child(1)').children().fadeIn(300);

        activeIndex = $('div.slider div.active').index() + 1;
        console.log(activeIndex);

        $('div.slides i.fa-circle')
          .removeClass('fa-circle')
          .addClass('fa-circle-o');
        $('div.slides i:nth-child(' +activeIndex+ ')')
          .removeClass('fa-circle-o')
          .addClass('fa-circle');
      };
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```